# Is there word for person who committed suicide?

Tags: nouns

A person who committed a theft is a thief.
A person who committed murder is a killer(or murderer?).

What is a person who committed suicide?

Comment: Yes, to echo Dan, they are called literally a "suicide"

But depending on how religious you get, you may hear other vocabulary. But I won't go there (even though you hinted at it)

Comment: [_Felo de se_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felo_de_se), Latin for "felon of himself", is an archaic legal term meaning suicide

Comment: **1.1A person who does this.** http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/suicide

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We quite literally call the person "*a suicide*".

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suicide#Noun) has the following example:

> 1. (countable) A person who has intentionally killed him/herself.
>
>    "I remember one suicide," she said to Philip, "who threw himself into the Thames."
>      1915, W. Somerset Maugham, Of Human Bondage, ch. 95

Comment: What is the source of the information?

Comment: +1 but as @kris suggests, a link to your source and a textual reference to it is considered best practice on this site.

Comment: added a reference, example, and link (Wiktionary)

Answer (score -1):

**victim** can be used.

> The suicide victim was 30 year old man from Smalltown.

Source: google 'suicide victim' you'll see plenty of usage.